# Checking that conditions are met before adding the order to the database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to make sure that the user has selected a waiter id (The first if statement) and that the id is valid and relates to a record in the database(The else if statement).

I am collecting the `id` from a `Number (GUI Text in Android)` and selecting the `Number` value like so

```
 EditText waiter_id;
 waiter_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waiter_id);
```

`TextUtils.isEmpty(waiter_id.getText()` checks to make sure a value has been entered and displays a message if not this works.

After I am calling a method created in the `DataBaseHelper isEmployee(String id)` class which uses the `id` entered by the user to search the database for that record. If the id is not found in the database then a message should appear to alert the user.

**Order onClick OrderActivity**

```
order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Order order;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(waiter_id.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, "Please select waiter id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // This is where the method which returns the boolean is called using
                // the value in the Number field in xml file
                } else if (!dbHelp.isEmployee(String.valueOf(waiter_id))){
                    Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, "Id not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

              

        });
```

**Method for querying the database DataBaseHelper Class**

```
public Boolean isEmployee(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String findEmployeeUsingId = "SELECT * FROM " + EMP_TABLE +
            " WHERE " + ID_EMP + " = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(findEmployeeUsingId, null);


    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

The error message I am receivingis:

```
com.example.dropit E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ".": syntax error in "SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE ID = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{93d8cbb VFED..CL. .F...... 249,193-829,317 #7f08011f app:id/waiter_id aid=1073741824}"

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE ID = androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{93d8cbb VFED..CL. .F...... 249,193-829,317 #7f08011f app:id/waiter_id aid=1073741824}

    at com.example.dropit.DataBaseHelper.isEmployee(DataBaseHelper.java:283)
    at com.example.dropit.OrderActivity$1.onClick(OrderActivity.java:58)
```

Comment: First use parameters, second debug what `String.valueOf(waiter_id))` returns

Comment: Please explain the down vote, it returns a `String`

Comment: What string?... Obviously not the one you want *After I am calling a method created in the DataBaseHelper isEmployee(String id) class which uses the id entered by the user to search*  this is not true... Check the string

Comment: A `String` representation of the `int` argument which is what I want, its the number of the users id the have entered

Comment: *A String representation of the int argument* No, it is not... Please, debug your program fist

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waiter_id` is an `EditText` and not a string.
When you call `isEmployee()` you should pass its text:

```
else if (!dbHelp.isEmployee(waiter_id.getText().toString()))
```

Also use a `?` placeholder inside `rawQuery()` instead of concatenating the parameter:

```
String findEmployeeUsingId = "SELECT * FROM " + EMP_TABLE + " WHERE " + ID_EMP + " = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(findEmployeeUsingId, new String[] {id});
```

Comment: Thank you I understand I thought because the `input` type was `Number` that it was a `int` but thanks for clarifying that it is actually `text`